# Extracting the dimension of a netcdf variable in python

Tags: python, netcdf, netcdf4

Considering a given dataset "data", extracted from a netcdf4 file containing a variable named clcalispo2.  I am working with python and f I do:

`print(data['clcalipso2'].ncattrs())`

I got this output:

`clcalipso2 <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>`
`float32 clcalipso2(levStat, loc)`
     `long_name: CALIPSO Cloud Fraction Undetected by CloudSat`
     `units: %`
     `standard_name: cloud_area_fraction_in_atmosphere_layer`
`unlimited dimensions:`
`current shape = (40, 153)`
`filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used`

I can easily extract the field attribute by doing:

`print(data['clcalipso2'].ncattrs())`

which yields:

`['long_name', 'units', 'standard_name']`

But me I am actually interested in extracting the variable dimension name, in this example: (levStat, loc). There is a simple way to do it (appart than using the output as a string and doing some string manipulations?)

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 1):

I found the soluition, I am posting it here in case that may be useful for somebody else:

```
print(data['clcalipso2'].dimensions)
```

yields

```
(levStat, loc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Note, I came to this looking for a different answer,
"what are the dimensions of a netcdf variable?"

Found that  if I have a netcdf class where I loaded the u and v wind component (with the dimensions of (longitude, latitude, level, time).

I wanted to know that its dimension was 4.

This worked print(nc.variables['u'].ndim)

Comment: Please use code formatting for better readability

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32836915)